# to_mysql inserts more rows in SQL table than there are in pandas dataframe

Tags: mysql, pandas, xampp

So I have a MySQL database, let's call it "MySQLDB". When trying to create a new table (let's call it datatable) and insert data from a pandas dataframe, my code keeps adding rows to the SQL table, and I'm not sure if they are duplicates or not. For reference, there are around 50,000 rows in my pandas dataframe, but after running my code, the SQL table contains over 1 million rows. Note that I am using XAMPP to run a local MySQL server on which the database "MYSQLDB" is stored. Below is a simplified/generic version of what I am running. Note I have removed the port number and replaced it with generic [port] in this post.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import mysql.connector

pandas_db = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col = [0])

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost:[port]/MySQLDB', echo=False)

pandas_db.to_sql(name='datatable', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', chunksize = 100, index=False)
```

Is something wrong with the code? Or could it be something to do with XAMPP or the way I set up my database? If there is anything I could improve, please let me know.

I haven't found any other good posts that describe having the same issue.

Comment: Change the input file from 50000 line to a lot less lines (maybe 10). When that fails share those 10 lines, and share the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE datatable;`.   (Changing the file to a small file will lead to a [mre], which can help others help you...)

Comment: @Luuk When I use an input file with 10 rows, then the code works completely fine - meaning all of them are inserted correctly into the data table.

Comment: OK, then you need to do some research to find (a couple of lines) which will no be imported correctly.  Probably they have a carriage-return in the line?  But that is impossible to tell without input file, and without a proper description of this `datatable`